# How to make one table to many class in EDMX design

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

This my main class

```
public partial class MainAcc
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Type1 { get; set; }
        public string Type2 { get; set; }
        public string Type3 { get; set; }
    }
```

and in EDMX design i make new entity base type MainAcc, i delete some column that i want to move in EDMX design, so it become like this after i save

```
public partial class MainAcc
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Type1 { get; set; }
    }

public partial class ChildAcc : MainAcc
    {
        public string Type2 { get; set; }
        public string Type3 { get; set; }
    }
```

In design my ChildAcc entity use table map of MainAcc. and after all i got error like this:

Error 3032: Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines 2877, 2907:EntityTypes MyModel.MainAcc, MyModel.ChildAcc are being mapped to the same rows in table MainAcc. Mapping conditions can be used to distinguish the rows that these types are mapped to.

That error in text editor is in MainAcc.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can't do this. I think these should be two different tables, but they can be related by some foreign key.

I tried `Database First` and `Model First` and the script I ended up adding showed that this would be two different tables related to each other.

Perhaps you expect to have one-to-one or one-to-many relationships, but that doesn't happen within a single table. If you go the `Database First` way, changing the model may result in an inconsistency with the current context. If the `Model First` method is adopted, two tables will be automatically generated after the model relationship is established.

I also tried to use table splitting for table mapping, but there are some limitations for dependent entity types, and derived types cannot be mapped to the same table.

Helpful Links:

[Advanced table mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/table-splitting)

[Model First](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/workflows/model-first)

[Configure One-to-Many Relationships in EF 6](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: I just finish my scenario and it can actually, i just add condition and it work so smooth

Comment: Hi @taufiqullr, could you please share your solution?